# How I can conect android with mysqldatabase?

Tags: android, mysql

I have a miniproject to do with mysql.I try many way to connect android with mysql such as

1. change them to 127.0.0.1
2. change them to ip
3. change them to 10.0.2.2 and set up on eclipse peference

I have trid for two weeks but I can't do.

 My note book is dell vostro 3450 64 bits

**p.s. Would you mind If I asked URL from real host?

This is my code.

**getjson.php**

```
<?
    $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    $objDB = mysql_select_db("mydatabase");

    // $_POST["txtKeyword"] = "a"; // for Sample

    $strKeyword = $_POST["txtKeyword"];
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE 1 AND Name LIKE '%".$strKeyword."%'  ";

    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
    $resultArray = array();
    while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
    {
        $arrCol = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
        {
            $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
        }
        array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
    }

    mysql_close($objConnect);

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
?>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableRow
      android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Search Customer : "
        android:layout_span="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:ems="4" >

     </EditText>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="OK" />

    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />

  <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">   

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/listView1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="By.. ThaiCreate.Com" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

**activity_column.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/ColCustomerID" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="CustomerID"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ColName" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ColEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.myapp;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Permission StrictMode
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        // Perform action on click
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SearchData();
            }
        });

    }

    public void SearchData()
    {
         // listView1
        final ListView lisView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);   

        // editText1
        final EditText inputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); 

        /**
         * [{"CustomerID":"C001","Name":"Win Weerachai","Email":"win.weerachai@thaicreate.com" ,"CountryCode":"TH","Budget":"1000000","Used":"600000"},
         * {"CustomerID":"C002","Name":"John Smith","Email":"john.smith@thaicreate.com" ,"CountryCode":"EN","Budget":"2000000","Used":"800000"},
         * {"CustomerID":"C003","Name":"Jame Born","Email":"jame.born@thaicreate.com" ,"CountryCode":"US","Budget":"3000000","Used":"600000"},
         * {"CustomerID":"C004","Name":"Chalee Angel","Email":"chalee.angel@thaicreate.com" ,"CountryCode":"US","Budget":"4000000","Used":"100000"}]
         */

        String url = "http://10.0.2.2/android/getJSON.php";

        // Paste Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtKeyword", inputText.getText().toString()));

        try {
            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url,params));

            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;

            for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("CustomerID", c.getString("CustomerID"));
                map.put("Name", c.getString("Name"));
                map.put("Email", c.getString("Email"));
                map.put("CountryCode", c.getString("CountryCode"));
                map.put("Budget", c.getString("Budget"));
                map.put("Used", c.getString("Used"));
                MyArrList.add(map);

            }


            SimpleAdapter sAdap;
            sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, MyArrList, R.layout.activity_column,
                    new String[] {"CustomerID", "Name", "Email"}, new int[] {R.id.ColCustomerID, R.id.ColName, R.id.ColEmail});      
            lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap);

            final AlertDialog.Builder viewDetail = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            // OnClick Item
            lisView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView,
                        int position, long mylng) {

                    String strCustomerID = MyArrList.get(position).get("CustomerID")
                            .toString();
                    String sName = MyArrList.get(position).get("Name")
                            .toString();
                    String strEmail = MyArrList.get(position).get("Email")
                            .toString();
                    String strCounryCode = MyArrList.get(position).get("CounryCode")
                            .toString();
                    String strBudget = MyArrList.get(position).get("Budget")
                            .toString();
                    String strUsed = MyArrList.get(position).get("Used")
                            .toString();

                    viewDetail.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
                    viewDetail.setTitle("Member Detail");
                    viewDetail.setMessage("MemberID : " + strCustomerID + "\n"
                            + "Name : " + sName + "\n" 
                            + "strEmail : " + strEmail + "\n" 
                            + "strCounryCode : " + strCounryCode + "\n" 
                            + "strBudget : " + strBudget + "\n"
                            + "Used : " + strUsed);
                    viewDetail.setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    viewDetail.show();

                }
            });


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public String getJSONUrl(String url,List<NameValuePair> params) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) { // Download OK
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Log", "Failed to download file..");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Describe the error you get/how your implementation behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (! $objConnect)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

And check the coming message on client if it returns any error and show us.

Comment: Hi Serdar S.


I can connect to mysql with php as well.

thank.